# Grabar en la tabla los valores del producto de un SELECT PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

```php
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT 
    SUM(p.cantidad * p.metros * e.peso ) total,
    p.id,  
    (e.peso*p.metros)peso,
    e.seccion,
    i.producto,
    p.cantidad,
    p.metros,
    p.unidad,
    o.descripcion,
    o.id_cliente
    FROM presupuestotemporal as p 
      INNER JOIN inventario as i 
      INNER JOIN equivalencias as e 
      INNER JOIN obras as o 
        ON p.id_producto = i.id 
        AND e.seccion = p.seccion 
        AND p.id_obra = o.id 
        AND p.id_obra = $id 
   GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.id ASC");
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Gabriel, usa la opción [edit] para explicar cual es el problema. Tu código no "graba" nada. Tampoco mostras la estructura de tus tablas o como se conectan entre sí. Así como esta, esta pregunta no se puede responder y va a terminar cerrada.